# Как сделать событие с параметром на кнопку через скрипт

Tags: c#, unity3d, делегаты

Столкнулся с такой проблемой.

Есть список кнопок созданных инстантиэйтом из префаба. Нужно так же скриптом присвоить им событие на клик, в которое передать индекс кнопки.

Я пробовал в цикле создания, к кнопке в onClick делать AddListener с методом, но просто так передать туда индекс как аргумент оно не дает.
Пишет не удаётся преобразовать void в UnityAction.

Я нашёл где то как сделать это с помощью делегатов (в них не шарю).
Сейчас я делаю вот это...

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{  
   Items[i].SelectB.onClick.AddListener(
      delegate { DoSomething(i); });
}
```

И в DoSomething просто дебаг лог с выводом индекса. Но при нажатии на любую кнопку выводится только ма симальный индекс +1, тоесть значение count.

Как это исправить или как правильно сделать событие на кнопках с их индексом в параметре?

Comment: Если писать в место делегата () => { DoSomething(i); }, то происходит тоже самое

Comment: для начала, попробуйте поменять `Items[I]` на `Items[i]`

Comment: А та это я с телефона пишу, пришлось переписать код XD

Comment: хорошо, попробуйте явно написать лог: `Items[i].SelectB.onClick.AddListener(() => Debug.Log(i));`

Comment: Не помогло, тоже самое

Answer (score 0):

А не проще на префаб с кнопкой повесить скрипт подписанный на событие этой кнопки и возвращающий событие с тем что ты ему укажешь?

```
public class OnClickObjectCallback : MonoBehaviour
{
    public event Action<GameObject> OnPerform;
    public GameObject Target;

    public void OnClick ()
    {
        if (Target != null && OnPerform != null)
            OnPerform.Invoke(Target);
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Foo : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private GameObject[] _targets;
    [SerializeField] private OnClickObjectCallback _buttonTemplate;

    private void Start ()
    {
        foreach (var target in _targets)
        {
            var btn = Instantiate(_buttonTemplate);
            btn.Target = target;
            btn.OnPerform += Spawn;
        }
    }

    private void Spawn (GameObject target)
    {
        Instantiate(target);
    }
}
```

Подобный скрипт может даже не просто быть калбеком, а принимать модель типа `ScriptableObject` содержащую иконку, имя, ссылку на префаб, меняет картинку и текст кнопки при указании модели... логично.

Comment: Просто интересно на самом деле, почему у меня так происходит, как будто оно обращается к ссылке на i, которая в конце цикла стала максимальным числом. Ну ведь этож не класс и тд, ну а выглядит так...